# Ubuntu 16.04 VA-API problem with iGPU / ESXI passthrough

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, vmware, vaapi

I have a ESXi box running Ubuntu 16.04 guest. It is i5-5300U (so all technologies to enable Intel GPU PCI passthrough).

I installed vainfo + i965-va-driver and all the dependancies and `vainfo` fails:

```
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva error: va_getDriverName() failed with unknown libva error,driver_name=(null)
vaInitialize failed with error code -1 (unknown libva error),exit
```

if I force driver with `LIBVA_DRIVER_NAME=i965 vainfo` or `DRI_PRIME=1 vainfo`:

```
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.4
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns -1
libva info: User requested driver 'i965'
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
vainfo: intel_driver.c:106: intel_driver_init: Assertion `VA_CHECK_DRM_AUTH_TYPE(ctx, VA_DRM_AUTH_DRI1) || VA_CHECK_DRM_AUTH_TYPE(ctx, VA_DRM_AUTH_DRI2) || VA_CHECK_DRM_AUTH_TYPE(ctx, VA_DRM_AUTH_CUSTOM)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm at my wits end because it worked with some interation of drivers (Intel update tool, 3rd party PPAs, etc.), on the same system with the result:

```
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
error: can't connect to X server!
libva info: VA-API version 0.39.2
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_39
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.39 (libva 1.7.3)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Broadwell - 1.7.1
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
(...)
```

Then I rebooted to never see this success again.

How would you approach to troubleshoot it?

### System

```
System:    Host: websrv Kernel: 4.4.0-92-generic x86_64 (64 bit) Console: tty 0 Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: VMware product: VMware Virtual Platform
           Mobo: Intel model: 440BX Desktop Reference Platform Bios: Phoenix v: 6.00 date: 04/05/2016
CPU(s):    4 Single core Intel Core i5-5300Us (-SMP-) speed: 2294 MHz (max)
Graphics:  Card-1: VMware SVGA II Adapter
           Card-2: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
           Display Server: N/A driver: N/A tty size: 238x74 Advanced Data: N/A out of X
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe my solution can be useful for others:

```
sudo chgrp video /dev/dri -R
sudo chmod 666 /dev/dri/*
sudo chmod 755 /dev/dri
```

voila!

Comment: It's better to add your user to the needed groups to access the files under /dev/dri. In Ubuntu for example: `sudo adduser <user> video` and `sudo adduser <user> render` (replace <user> with your username).